# Javascript for replacing $ with $$ or $latex

Tags: javascript, wordpress, latex

I do know good HTML and some PHP, but not at all javascript, so I need some help with this question please. I have a wordpress site the uses math equations together with Simple Matjax plugin for rendering the math from latex. There are many worpress plugins for latex some of them faster, some of them slower. 
I tried to find a faster plugin to replace Simple Mathjax, but every other plugin use a different math "quotation" than that I am using $...$
So I need a javascript that either replaces the $...$ with $$...$$ or first $ with $latex (or whatever start and end sequence I might need for a specific plugin). I guess this is simple, but as I was saying, I do not know javascript at all. Thank you.

PS. There is one replacement WP Quick Latex but when I install it it block the access to my homepage (all other pages are rendered and displayed, except my homepage, page 2, page 3,...that contain excertpts). Any suggestions? Edit: Quicklatex uses shortcodes [latexpage]. If one enables it sitewide on the homepage it has to work on all equations, Thus the wating time for loading the homepage increases significantly.

Comment: Site is www.show-my-homework.com

Comment: Is this a java question or a javascript question.  They are NOT the same language.

Comment: Javascript. I got the answer. Thank you.

Comment: If you got the answer, you should credit the person by accepting their answer.  Also, as Stephen mentioned, you should edit your question to change "java" to "JavaScript" to avoid future readers of any confusion.  The two languages are very different!

Comment: I credited the answer yesterday, just that I have under 15 points or so, and it does not show as credited. Please excuse me. Edit: I just upvoted it yesterday, I credited it now.

Comment: For all wordpress users: there is a plugin which is doing this in wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript function for string replacement is

```
replace("string to replace", "new string")
```

I think you should do something like this:

```
var string = "$"; // <-- this is where you enter the string you want to replace
var new_replaced_string = string.replace("$", "$latex");
```

Hope this helps.